# google oAuth display popup cancel button not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-oauth

I want to access Google services, which requires authenticate such as OAuth2.
Every things is working fine according my requirement.

**Steps:**

- User clicks on the "Authorize" button
- Browser opens a popup window that request for permission to access data
- User clicks on the "Accept" button
- Popup window closes automatically

**Problem**

if I click the cancel button I remain redirect me the same popup accept and cancel page. I have been searching for a solution but could not find any. Has anyone encountered similar problems?

Comment: I can't understand what the problem is "if I click the cancel button I remain redirect me the same popup accept and cancel page.", can you clarify?

Comment: thanks @william Denniss for you comment.. i have solve above problem..it's my coding logic problem..